# webpack breaks electron-notifications

Tags: webpack, electron

I've tried `electron-notifications` in sample app and they worked well. Then I've tried to integrate them into an existing big project, which uses `webpack` to build the app. And in this app `electron-notifications` do not work properly. They are broken there in a weird way - these notifications do appear, but they have no styles, no content. They appear just as white empty rectangles. There are no errors shown by webpack or in electron's dev tools window. I've created [this dumb app](https://github.com/avmax/electron-demo/tree/electron-notifications---webpack) to check what breaks `electron-notifications` - and it is `webpack`.

Can anyone please suggest any solutions how to fix my webpack config to make this plugin work properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you set the target correctly? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/

Comment: @thomasmeadows I did:  `target: 'electron-renderer'`

Comment: you probably need to use remote.require as it is a node module not a browser module. 
 https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md